# How to determine the borders of drawn images using Java?

Tags: java, image, javafx, colors, outline

I'm new to JavaFx and I want to create a coloring book app.

I'm thinking of drawing the images by hand - using Photoshop or scanning the drawings.

These image files will be imported in Java. Then I'm planning on using Java/JavaFX to define the outlines of the images. Once the outlines/borders are defined, then I can color the areas in.

How can I define the outlines/borders of the drawings using Java/JavaFX? Are there any pre-existing libraries so I can use?

Thank you